# how to replace a tile floor over radiant heat

Tags: flooring, tile, radiant-heating

I just purchased a home and the kitchen has radiant heated porcelain tile floor in the kitchen. The floor is in rough shape so Id like to redo it. This raises a number of questions.

1. should I try to keep the existing floor? and maybe restain it? its currently a terracotta color (it that an option)
2. would it be easier to just put another layer of tile over the existing floor? will the radiant heat still be effective?
3. Should I pull up the floor and put a whole new floor down? Im concerned that this will ruin the radiant flooring?

Additional info based on comments:

1. it is hot water radiant heat
2. it is over a basement with wood floor joists
3. the house was built in 2000

here is a shot of the floor:
[image]

Any and all comments and suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you post a picture? Do you know what type of radiant heat? Is it an electric mat, or recirculated hot water from a boiler?

Comment: Also is this on slab? Or is there basement/crawlspace etc underneath?  If basement are the joists wood?

Comment: Its recirculated hot water and its over a basement. The joists are wood. Ill take a pic and post when I can. thx

Comment: That says a lot about what’s there, when you edit to add the pic be sure to include that info in the question, as well as the age of the house if you know or have a good guess.  That also says much about how it was created.

Comment: Tyson: updated the original post with the info you requested. thx

Comment: To be honest I’d love to have that tile in my kitchen, kiln baked terra-cotta, it’s a high end floor material, my .02 cents is that it needs refinishing periodically but unless you absolutely can’t stand it, I’d refinish it with clear coat-gloss or matte— and be done with it.  Staining darker or at all is more problematic because you will have to strip completely first, the stain will soak up differently in high traffic areas where more finish has worn down.

Comment: Some wear in a floor is actually interesting--it's as much a feature as a defect. You really need to think about messing with this floor. At least live with it for a while and see if the visual effect of the wear areas can be dealt with individually.

Comment: @Tyson I am not fond of the tile - but I sure do like the space of that Kitchen. :-)

Comment: @JimStewart they do take a periodic coat of clear finish, I don’t know the specific product.  We had that tile in my dads house in AZ when I was young.  About every 6-10 years it needed refinishing.  We had a non-glossy matte finish which I prefer but I’ve seen it glossy too.

Comment: If left un-refinished the result is the porous finish collects dirt and grease quickly and the floor seems impossible to clean and keep clean.